# What do the colors of the light shining from the Gacha door mean?

Tags: danmachi-memoria-freese

When you roll there is a silver, gold, or rainbow light that comes out from the Gacha door... What exactly does this light mean?

I have received Ultra Rare 4★ units when I had a gold door with no guaranteed unit and I have also gotten a gold door when I was guaranteed a 4★ unit.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, the light colour S correspond to the rarity inside but sometimes you can get a 4 Star in a gold door